# How to disable notification e-mails from bookings in shared calendar?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I work at a school and have just created a group where I added all employees, to be able to have a shared calendar for external bookings. It works and everyone in the organization can create a meeting which everyone can see. However, when someone creates a booking it is automatically sent an email to everyones email box. I want to turn this feature off so these notification emails are not sent.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Outlook desktop client? Or just Outloo.com account on the web? If so, please refer to this :https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/16714903-shared-calendar-notifications